# TypeScript overloads doesn't chose the expected one

Tags: typescript, generics, overloading

Let's say I have some code below:

```js
type Func1<T1> = (arg1: T1) => any;

type FuncArray<T1> = (arg1: T1, b: string) => any

interface Callable {
    <T>(fn: Func1<T>, arg1: T): string
    <T1>(fn: FuncArray<T1>, arg1: T1): number
}

const call: Callable = (...args: any): any => { }

interface Config {
    url?: string
    headers?: { [K: string]: string | number }
}

interface Requests {
    (config: Config): string
    (url: string, config?: Config): string
}

const request: Requests = (url: string | Config, config?: Config) => '123'

const h = call(request, {}) // error: Argument of type 'Requests' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FuncArray<string>'.
  // Types of parameters 'config' and 'arg1' are incompatible.
    // Type 'string' has no properties in common with type 'Config'.
```

The error indicate that `call` is using its second overload signature, which I thought it would use its first overload in this specific case.

My understanding is that `request` should match `Requests` first overload, and then `call(request, {})` matches `Callable` first overload, but actually it does't. Where do I get it wrong?

So my question is **Why `call(request, {})` does not match `<T>(fn: Func1<T>, arg1: T): string`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue doesn't have to do with `Callable`'s overloads.  You can see this for yourself by commenting out the second overload:

```
interface Callable {
    <T>(fn: Func1<T>, arg1: T): string
    //<T1>(fn: FuncArray<T1>, arg1: T1): number
}
```

Then you see the error:

```
const h = call(request, {}) // error!
// -------------------> ~~
// Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

So the compiler has looked at `request` and inferred that `T` is type `string`, and then `{}` does not match `string` and you get an error.  So the issue is that the compiler does not accept `call(request, {})` as a match for `Callable`'s first overload.

If you uncomment `Callable`'s second overload, the compiler sees that it doesn't match the second overload either, and the error changes to "no overload matches this call".  So let's not worry about `FuncArray`.

---

So why does `call(request, {})` not match the first `Callable` overload?

The problem is that *`Requests`* is an overloaded function interface, and [generic type parameter inference cannot do overload resolution at the same time](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30369#issuecomment-476402214).  It's a design limitation of TypeScript.  When the compiler sees `call(request, {})` it has to infer the type of `T`. Instead of trying to determine which of the two overloads of `Requests` it should try to match against, *it just picks the last one*.   And `(url: string, config?: Config)=> string` matches `Func1<string>`.  And everything goes wrong from there.

---

So what can you do?  The easiest thing is to manually specify the generic parameter to relieve the compiler of the burden of inferring it:

```
const h = call<Config>(request, {}) // okay
```

Once you specify that `T` is `Config`, the compiler *then* can do overload resolution on `request` and verify that, yes, `request` is a valid `Func1<Config>`.  Similarly you can widen the type of `request` via type assertion to just `Func1<Config>`, so that `T` is correctly inferred:

```
const i = call(request as Func1<Config>, {}); // okay
```

Either way should work.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAFATgewEYBsJiQG8BYAKCQqQBcBPGZAMQFdh4BGAHgBU2A+JALxIAFCDQBzNgC4kPAJSD+IYDQDcZMpWp1GLeAEE0aEDW59BIsZJk8ANEiwyoVNAEtg4hQKUqN5Su5UEGgAZgjIAMIgODgguMgk-loU3LzCIcAyzKycXLz2VtKyck4u7uKayRQA9NVmaRlZeobGpjz5SIU2bCVIwExgWMGVFAC+flrwGMDOSPDRODJRMXF4FsIAdFtWUDLKNL37ikRI46QjSIHBYYhIEdMhruJEF1pMaDgA-KVuHq+UAAsICAACbBKDfE4AbQA0j9ygBdeEeJAAHz6AyGaFOFzOFyuoXCSAAShAAI5MaBUKAvJLJYRTYCPcRLB5PXrOX4VOlaYTvRZITnleyM5mQ+5M9nI7laPF0xmzNDkynOGSkilUmlCPkfaVou5s8Qiw3iw1efgAcjYACYAMwWiaUBVUJAAizzGLCJUa5z2QijBS1JDBTBoACEFyDAFoY7G4-G4-wAH5JyPVJCGcQDCDAF0YELaehIC3+i2XGnADAukBQKBPUDxagYJBwYyQILY-OF5AWoUeC0bPxnUCQWBElAYWuueIAZQwOCYVFc01pSAutCL2XY9XWXVkPWO+3U5zpG90rBaJh32r3dgc0vNnV8J60BJukQWqwS-xSeXSmSQLdcg6W8OTKP4eUoVJ-yaC8jCvPICgkIouF6fpBmGOk5UmaZZg9AVlliRttS2DYdj2FRDhUY5CBxF8Alza4iQlZlVyqJB+UhPsZXYoFQXBSFaNhaUkUFcDnnRdCsTo2VHQoN8iXVFVqTYqoGUNVlJU8aUfxEflpWNLTTS0sCuVxOS5lwl1vWUtVlU1dZ9LErl9RYp5DLFTTmUfK07QdeiKGdV13QWDg3PENIbKpP0AyQIMMAAaxMC4gtcELPSi2Ya0AvROHCjp-TkVQ4vTRLkrpIcgA)

Comment: Very helpful! TypeScript v3.7.2 has a different error message with v3.6.2, and it seems that v3.7.2 is more informative about some errors.